# Processing SSAS Tabular model Fails Remote Server

Tags: ssms, ssas

I'm trying to create a SSAS Project and deploy to a remote server.
The Data Source is a Database in the same server, but the project must be made in my laptop.

The remote server is not in a domain environment, so to login in SSAS, I used runas /netonly mothod using Server's Administrator Account, which works fine to connect to SSAS Server through SSMS.

I created SSAS Project using Workspace Server and connection is successful.
I am also able to connect to same Server using SQL Server Database Data Source, using Impersonate Service Account, but after I select the tables I need, the processing fails and gives me this Error:

```
Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'OLE DB or ODBC error: [DataSource.Error] Microsoft SQL: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The wait operation timed out.).
```

And as result I get all tables without data, just column names.

**If I create a project using Integrated Workspace, I am able to get Data from Source, but the same Error occurs when I try to Deploy the Project. The metadata deploys successfully, but all processing fails with the same Error.**

I tried to Increase Timeout, but the same thing happens even after waiting 30 minutes.

This process does not fail if I create and execute the project inside the Server.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the TCP/IP in both Server NetWork and Client protocols;
Set TCP port:1433;
And then try it again.

Please reference this: [troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: TCP/IP is enabled in a custom port which we use to connect to SSAS and it works fine.